# Media wiki second POST still returns NeedToken result

Tags: javascript, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

After first POST request I get "NeedToken" result then in my second POST request I pass token and sessionid as parameters.  Here is my Javascript code:

```
function wiki_auth(login, pass, ref){
    $.post(ref+'api.php?action=login&lgname=' + login +
            '&lgpassword=' + pass + '&format=json', function(data) {
        if(data.login.result == 'NeedToken') {
            $.post(ref+'api.php?action=login&lgname=' + login +
                    '&lgpassword=' + pass + '&lgtoken='+data.login.token+'&format=json&sessionid='+data.login.sessionid+'&lgdomain='+ref,
                    function(data) {
                if(!data.error){
                   if (data.login.result == "Success") {
                        document.location.href=ref;
                   } else {
                        console.log('Result: '+ data.login.result);
                   }
                } else {
                   console.log('Error: ' + data.error);
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Result: ' + data.login.result);
        }
        if(data.error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data.error);
        }
    });
}
```

I am not sure if I need to pass something else as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to actually [POST the parameters as `data`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) (in the *body* of the HTTP request), not append them to the GET parameters in the url. Use

```
$.post(ref+'api.php?action=login&format=json', {
    lgname: login,
    lgpassword: pass,
    lgtoken: data.login.token,
    sessionid: data.login.sessionid,
    lgdomain: ref
}, function(data) { … });
```

Comment: There is no difference with your code. Result of second post is still "NeedToken". Maybe cookie is not being handled properly?

Comment: Hm, it should work. The cookie should be automatically handled by the browser (and since it's `HttpOnly`, you can't manipulate it anyway). Could you maybe edit your question and post the http request as seen in your devtools' network inspector?

Comment: It turns out that I had to handle cookies manually, but also have the parameters in the body of the request.

Comment: How did you need to handle cookies (that sessionid?) manually? Are you not in a browser environment? You might also [answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), I'd be really interesting in the code you needed for that.