# MW API Login Need token even on second post request

Tags: jquery, mediawiki, mediawiki-api

The answer to this question **[Media wiki second POST still returns NeedToken result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21238407/media-wiki-second-post-still-returns-needtoken-result)** does not solve the problem

I am trying to login to my mediawiki api, through a jquery script. This requires me to send 2 Post requests one with the username and password and second with the token received with the first request.

When I do these 2 post requests, using the Chrome REST-client extension, I receive a success result in the 2nd post response.

But using the jquery script, I am unable to do this. I mean instead of a success, i receive a NeedToken on my second response, which should actually give me success.

This is what my first request returns in both the jquery script and the Chrome REST Client

```
{"login:{"result":"NeedToken","token":"37b4b5893b358884406c3b5125c49071","cookieprefix":"vanisource_vanisource_","sessionid":"cbbe4723035434728ee15fcbe8402921"}}
```

and second response that I get from the Rest Client in Chrome is

```
{"login":{"result":"Success","lguserid":10,"lgusername":"Test",
"lgtoken":"8cbe78566c9ac67b41ea82bf54fc169e",
"cookieprefix":"vanisource_vanisource_","sessionid":"dbc0d6ca3c7882f7058784cbf9c29b7d"}}
```

but i receive something like this from the script for the second post request

```
{login: {result:NeedToken, token:37b4b5893b358884406c3b5125c49071,....}}
```

Which is not expected. Following is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
function wiki_auth(login, pass, ref){
$.post('http://vanisource.org/w/api.php?action=login&format=json',
        {
            lgname: login,
            lgpassword: pass,
            lgdomain:'vanisource.org'

        },
        function(data) {
        console.log(data.login.sessionid);
        var myresult = data.login.result;
        console.log(myresult);
        if(data.login.result == 'NeedToken') {
        $.post('http://vanisource.org/w/api.php?action=login&format=json',
        {
            lgpassword: pass,
            lgname: login,
            lgtoken: data.login.token, 
            lgdomain:'vanisource.org'
        },

        function(data1) {

       console.log(data1.login.result);
       console.log(data1.login.sessionid);
        }
        );

}
}
)};
</script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
wiki_auth('test', 'wrongpassword', '/w/');
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I'd assume that your second request does not send the cookie along. Not sure why, though.

Comment: i tried putting the session id. But it doesnt help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that both requests should be sent from the same session. In your case they were sent in different session because *sessionid* values are different. The reason of this situation can be not accepting cookies.

If you can't accept cookies for some reasons, I can suggest you the following workaround:

After the first request save *cookieprefix* and *sessionid* parameters. Then put the following information in the header of the second request:

```
Cookie: cookieprefix_session:<sessionid from the 1st request>
```

In your case it will be

```
Cookie: vanisource_vanisource__session:cbbe4723035434728ee15fcbe8402921
```

This should help.